# I have 2 git branches develop and master but mistakenly some of the code is directly checked-in to master

Tags: github, git-stash

Some of the code is directly pushed to master which is not in develop branch

Also their is some code which is checked-in to develop but not merged to master yet

What would be the best possible way of syncing both branches so that both will have the same code

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would view the remote `master` branch as the ultimate authority regarding the state of your product.  Under this assumption, you might first update `develop` with the latest changes coming from `master`, and then push that updated `develop` branch back to `master`.  Here is one way:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout develop
git merge origin/master
# resolve any merge conflicts, etc.
git push origin develop
```

Then, you would look to merge `develop` into `master`.  If you are using something like GitHub, this might happen via a pull request.  So, you would create a pull request from `develop` pointing back to `master` as the target branch.  If you wanted to do the merge locally, then you could try:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
git push origin master
```

But most large software projects use a repo like GitHub or Bitbucket to prevent anyone from directly updating `master` in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, normally you commit to `develop` and then merge `develop` into `master`. `master` is always behind `develop`. Something like so.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
             \
              E - F - G [develop]
```

You can use `git log --decorate --graph` to get this sort of view of your repository.

But somebody made commits directly to `master`, `H - I` below, and you have this situation.

```
A - B - C - D - H - I [master]
             \
              E - F - G [develop]
```

Instead you want this.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
             \
              E - F - G - H - I [develop]
```

---

Again, we're here.

```
A - B - C - D - H - I [master]
             \
              E - F - G [develop]
```

You can use `git cherry-pick` to copy `H - I` on top of `develop`.

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick H I

A - B - C - D - H - I [master]
             \
              E - F - G - H1 - I1 [develop]
```

Then move `master` back to D.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard D

A - B - C - D [master]
             \
              E - F - G - H1 - I1 [develop]
```

Push both branches with `--force`.